# How to solve for variables with a pandas/matplotlib graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, equation

I'm learning Pandas. I've made a dictionary of data, and turned it into a DataFrame. then I plotted it as a line graph. I was curious how to treat that line graph as an equation, and get the result of an input variable?

For example:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphPoints = {"Number":[1,2,3,5,6],"value": [100.0,85.0,56.4,22.7,6.8]}

mydf = pandas.DataFrame(round1data)
myindexed_df = round1df.set_index('Number') 
myindexed_df.plot()

plt.show()
```

How do I then get the results of new values on that graph? i.e. if x = 4, y = ?? Is there some sort of y = plt(x) or similar thing with pandas or matplotlib?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood the scope of pandas and matplotlib. Pandas is a data organization tool. Matplotlib is a data visualisation tool. What you are requiring here is a data computation tool.

One possible tool to use is `numpy`.

In order to calculate the value of y at the position `x = 4`, you can interpolate the given arrays using `numpy.interp()`.

```
import numpy as np

number = np.array([1,2,3,5,6])
value  = np.array([100.0,85.0,56.4,22.7,6.8])

print (np.interp(4, number, value))
```

This prints `39.55`.

Now you may of course plot the result in a graph using matplotlib:

[image]

```
import numpy as np

number = np.array([1,2,3,5,6])
value  = np.array([100.0,85.0,56.4,22.7,6.8])

f = lambda x: np.interp(x, number, value)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(number, value, ls="-.", marker="o", label="values")
plt.plot(4, f(4), marker="s",markersize=8,  label="x = 4, y = {}".format(f(4)))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```